# Meta-analysis of three glm models with coefficient estimate

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, meta-analysis

I have ran three simple logistic regression models:

```r
glm(factor(response) ~ factor(sex) + age + gene expression,
    data = data_2,
    family = binomial)
```

Now I have for all three models the `Coefficient Estimate`, `Std. Error`, `z value` and `p-value` obtained via `summary(model)`.

Now I would like to combine all three studies via a meta-analysis, preferably using these results I obtained.

Could you guide me on how to do this.. Is it possible and if so, how could I do this?

Comment: Do you want to meta-analyse one coefficient or all of them simultaneusly?

Comment: Only of the coefficient gene expression.

Comment: OK. You need the coefficient and its standard error. The plug them in to one of the packages in R which does meta-analysis. Most people use either meta or metafor. They are both available from CRAN. Advice about package use is off-topic here so if you get stuck perhaps try on the mailing list dedicated to R meta-analysis https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//